# Task.Factory.FromAsync with "out" parameters in End Method

Tags: c#, async-await

How do I use the Task.Factory.FromAsync factory for an end method that returns multiple values via "out" parameters?

The begin method has this signature:

```
public virtual System.IAsyncResult BeginGetCaseStatus(int CaseOID, int ClientOID, System.AsyncCallback @__Callback, object @__UserData)
```

End method is:

```
public virtual void EndGetCaseStatus(System.IAsyncResult @__AsyncResult, out DTGenericCode[] BasicStatus, out DTGenericCode[] ARStatus)
```

Can I some how use:

```
public Task<?> GetCaseStatusAsync(int CaseOID, int ClientOID)
{
    return Task.Factory.FromAsync  (BeginGetCaseStatus(CaseOID, ClientOID, null, null), EndGetCaseStatus(?, ?));
}
```

Comment: That is not a standard APM End*** call, so the FromAsync methods won't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no `FromAsync` overload that would work for this.  The best option would likely be to build your own wrapper:

```
public class ResultStatus
{
     public ResultStatus(DTGenericCode[] basicStatus, DTGenericCode[] arStatus)
     {
         this.BasicStatus = basicStatus;
         this.ARStatus = arStatus;
     }
     public DTGenericCode[] BasicStatus { get; private set; }
     public DTGenericCode[] ARStatus { get; private set; }
}

public Task<ResultStatus> GetCaseStatusAsync(int CaseOID, int ClientOID)
{
     var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<ResultStatus>();
     theClass.BeginGetCaseStatus(CaseOID, ClientOID, iar =>
             {
                 DTGenericCode[] bs;
                 DTGenericCode[] as;
                 theClass.EndGetCaseStatus(iar, out bs, out as);

                 tcs.SetResult(new ResultStatus(bs, as));
             }, null);

     return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: Question, if `theClass.EndGetCaseStatus` raises an exception do you need to wrap it with a try-catch and pass the exception on to `tcs.SetException(`?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yes, and if there's a way to cancel, you should also set the cancellation flag (`tcs.SetCancelled()`).  This was the simplest possible wrapper to get the idea across, though.

Comment: “There is no `FromAsync` overload that would work for this.” Not directly, but you can make it work with a little bit of effort (see my answer).

Answer (score 7):

The `endMethod` parameter of `FromAsync()` is a delegate, so you can use a lambda to convert the `out`-form to the normal form of `-End` methods. Something like:

```
private static Task<Tuple<DTGenericCode[], DTGenericCode[]>> GetCaseStatusAsync(
    int CaseOID, int ClientOID)
{
    return Task.Factory.FromAsync(
        BeginGetCaseStatus, ar =>
        {
            DTGenericCode[] basicStatus;
            DTGenericCode[] arStatus;

            EndGetCaseStatus(ar, out basicStatus, out arStatus);

            return Tuple.Create(basicStatus, arStatus);
        },
        CaseOID, ClientOID, null);
}
```

Though you probably want to use a custom type instead of the `Tuple`.